# How to run cor.test with nested loops

Tags: r, loops, nested, correlation, data-analysis

I am trying to run a correlation test on different data frames representing the number of unique stores an employee is assigned and columns repenting different regions simultaneously. My data frame is split by the number of unique stores each employee has by:
`unique_store_breakdown <- split(Data, as.factor(Data$unique_stores))`

Ideally I would like the output:

```
Region -- unique_store -- correlation    
Midwest ------- 1 --------------  .05  
Midwest ------- 2 --------------  .04  
.  
.  
Southeast ----- 1 -------------  0.75  
.  
.
```

```
cor_tests <-list() 
counter = 0 

for (i in unique(j$region)){
for (j in 1: length(unique_store_breakdown)){
  counter = counter + 1
  #Create new variables for correlation test
  x = as.numeric(j[j$region == i,]$quality)
  y = as.numeric(j[j$region == i,]$rsv)

  cor_tests[[counter]] <- cor.test(x,y)
}}
cor_tests
```

I am able to run this for one dataframe at a time, but when I try to add the nested loop (j term) I receive the error "Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors. Additionally I would also like to output the results as a dataframe rather than a list if possible.

Comment: `j` is just an integer in your loop, why are you trying to use elements from it as if it was a dataframe?

Comment: Do you want to test the correlation between `quality` and `rsv` for each store?

Comment: Yes I am looking to test the correlation between quality and rsv for each iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is perform `cor.test()` for each store, it should be fairly simple using `by()`. The output from `by()` is a regular list, it's just the printing that is a little special.

```
# example data
set.seed(1)
dtf <- data.frame(store=rep(1:3, each=30), rsv=rnorm(90))
dtf$quality <- dtf$rsv + rnorm(90, 0, dtf$store)

# perform cor.test for every store
by(dtf, dtf$store, function(x) cor.test(x$quality, x$rsv))
# dtf$store: 1
# 
#   Pearson's product-moment correlation
# 
# data:  x$quality and x$rsv
# t = 5.5485, df = 28, p-value = 6.208e-06
# alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
# 95 percent confidence interval:
#  0.4915547 0.8597796
# sample estimates:
#       cor 
# 0.7236681 
# 
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# dtf$store: 2
# 
#   Pearson's product-moment correlation
# 
# data:  x$quality and x$rsv
# t = 0.68014, df = 28, p-value = 0.502
# alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
# 95 percent confidence interval:
#  -0.2439893  0.4663368
# sample estimates:
#       cor 
# 0.1274862 
# 
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# dtf$store: 3
# 
#   Pearson's product-moment correlation
# 
# data:  x$quality and x$rsv
# t = 2.2899, df = 28, p-value = 0.02977
# alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
# 95 percent confidence interval:
#  0.04304952 0.66261810
# sample estimates:
#      cor 
# 0.397159 
#
```